# LibGDX, vertical group not displaying

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I'm having trouble showing a simple custom `VerticalGroup`.

Here's my `SideBar` class:

```
public class SideBar extends VerticalGroup {
    final GameManager gameManager = GameManager.instance;
    final Image nextBackground;
    final Image nextImage;
    final Image powerImage;
    final Image powerUp1Background;
    final Image powerUp2Background;
    final Image powerUp3Background;


    public SideBar() {
        super();
        nextBackground = new Image(gameManager.getTexture("bar.next.png"));
        addActor(nextBackground);
        nextImage = new Image(gameManager.getTexture("label.next.png"));
        addActor(nextImage);
        powerImage = new Image(gameManager.getTexture("label.power.png"));
        addActor(powerImage);
        powerUp1Background = new Image(gameManager.getTexture("powerup.bg.png"));
        addActor(powerUp1Background);
        powerUp2Background = new Image(gameManager.getTexture("powerup.bg.png"));
        addActor(powerUp2Background);
        powerUp3Background = new Image(gameManager.getTexture("powerup.bg.png"));
        addActor(powerUp3Background);
    }
}
```

And here's where I add it to my main `Stage`:

```
    TopBar topBar = new TopBar();
    topBar.setY(DonutsGame.WORLD_HEIGHT - topBar.getHeight());
    stage.addActor(topBar);

    SideBar sideBar = new SideBar();
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "side bar - x,y: " + sideBar.getX() + "," + sideBar.getY() + ", w,h: " + sideBar.getWidth() + "," + sideBar.getHeight());
    stage.addActor(sideBar);
```

My `TopBar` class extends `Group` and is displaying correctly, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with `SideBar` that's causing it to not show.

The `log` output shows that the position, and width/height are all 0, which seems incorrect to me according to the vertical group's [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/VerticalGroup.html). Which states that the width/height should be based on the pref. width/height of the children (height based on sum).

I've tried calling `validate` and `layout` with no success.

Comment: If I manually set the width and height, then the group shows, and I just re-read the documentation. It actually says preferred width/height are based on children. However, the examples I can find don't say anything about having to set the width and height.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if the `VerticalGroup` is added to another layout, then it works. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/VerticalGroup.java), this is due to `VerticalGroup` also being a `Layout`, and so it's `prefWidth`/`Height` are used instead of the `getWidth`/`Height` methods.

I got around this by manually setting the size to the pref. size.

```
setSize(getPrefWidth(), getPrefHeight());
```

Note, that you don't need to do this if you're putting the `VerticalGroup` in another `WidgetGroup` like `Table` or `ScrollPane` since they use `prefWidth`/`Height` anyway.